# Unsure why xpath query coming back empty

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and am experimenting with the shell, attempting to retrieve products from the following URL: https://www.newbalance.co.nz/men/shoes/running/trail/?prefn1=sizeRefinement&prefv1=men_shoes_7

The following is my code - I'm not sure why the final query is coming back empty:

```
$ scrapy shell

fetch("https://www.newbalance.co.nz/men/shoes/running/trail/?prefn1=sizeRefinement&prefv1=men_shoes_7")
div_product_lists = response.xpath('//div[@id="product-lists"]')
ul_product_list_main = div_product_lists.xpath('//ul[@id="product-list-main"]')
for li_tile in ul_product_list_main.xpath('//li[@class="tile"]'):
...    print li_tile.xpath('//div[@class="product"]').extract()
...
[]
[]
```

If I inspect the page using a property inspector, then I am seeing data for the div (with class `product`), so am not sure why this is coming back empty.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Query coming back empty]

Comment: which attributes do you want to extract of highlighted div?

Comment: In plain English, I'm trying to get the name of the item and the price (e.g. in the example URL, "590v3 Trail" and $120.00 for the first item).

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  But if I replace the final line with just "//div" (rather than trying to restrict it to 'product') then I am getting results - so things must be working up to this point, e.g. >> for li_tile in ul_product_list_main.xpath('//li[@class="tile"]'):
...    print li_tile.xpath('//div')
...
[<Selector xpath='//div' data=u'<div style="display:none;">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r'>, <Selector xpath='//div' data=u'<div class="disabledcontainer">\n<div cla'>, <Selector xpath='//div' data=u'<div class="disabledmessag

Comment: P.S. Apologies for formatting - but can't see a nicer way to do this in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that xpath doesn't understand that `class="product product-tile "` means "This element has 2 classes, product and product-tile".
In an xpath selector, the class attribute is just a string, like any other.

Knowing that, you can search for the entire class string:

```
>>> li_tile.xpath('.//div[@class="product product-tile "]')
[<Selector xpath='.//div[@class="product product-tile "]' data='<div class="product product-tile " tabin'>]
```

If you want to find all the elements that have the "product" class, the easiest way to do so is using a css selector:

```
>>> li_tile.css('div.product')
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product ')]" data='<div class="product product-tile " tabin'>]
```

As you can see by looking at the resulting `Selector`, this is a bit more complicated to achieve using only xpath.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  Good to understand the reason why - thank you also for the css selector tip.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to extract is more readily available in other div having class `product-top-spacer`.

For instance you can get all divs having `class="product-top-spacer"` by following:

```
ts = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-top-spacer"]')
```

and check the item of first extracted div and its price:

```
ts[0].xpath('descendant::p[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
>> 'Leadville v3'

ts[0].xpath('descendant::div[@class="product-pricing"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
>> '$260.00'
```

All items can be viewed by iterating `ts`

```
for t in ts:
    itname = t.xpath('descendant::p[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
    itprice = t.xpath('descendant::div[@class="product-pricing"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    itprice = ' '.join(itprice.split()) # some cleaning
    print(itname + ", " + itprice)
```